# Consume SOAP web service having complex types

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I am new to ColdFusion and need to write code to consume a SOAP based web service.

Any links/pointers/examples for consuming SOAP based web service which has complex types will help.

When I am writing the code to consume the below web service in ColdFusion, how should I handle operation name, input msg, and complex types? Just need some pointers to get started.

XSD is something like :

```
<!--  S Request -->
    <xs:complexType name="SRequestHeader">
     + <xs:sequence>
     + <xs:element name="sID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">   </xs:element>
     + <xs:element name="orderNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">   </xs:element>
     + <xs:element name="dateCreated" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">   </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
  - <xs:complexType name="SOrderLine">
     - <xs:sequence>
     - <xs:element name="lineNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">   </xs:element>
     - <xs:element name="recordType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">   </xs:element>
     - <xs:element name="dueDate" minOccurs="1" type="xs:dateTime" />       
    </xs:complexType>
......
```

WSDL has :

```
<WL:portType name="SPortType">
- <WL:operation name="newOrder">   
    <WL:input message="WL:newOrderRequest" name="newOrderRequest" />    
    <WL:output> message="W:newOrderResponse" name="newOrderResponse" />    
    <WL:fault> message="WL:WSException" name="WSException" />    
  </WL:operation>
```

I am using something like:

```
<soapenv:Body>    
  <newOrder>
  <soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
      <sor:newOrderRequest>
         <sor:SOrderRequest>
            <sor:sID>S123</sor:sID> ....
```

And finally...

```
<cfhttp url="http://xxxx:123/YYY/SService" method="post" timeout="118"        
       throwonerror="yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(soap)#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#">
</cfhttp>
```

Getting **500 Internal Server Error**  on this line :

```
<cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#">
```

Comment: Pointer number 1 - you will probably want to create an object.  There is a tag, <cfobject> and a function, CreateObject() that allow you to do this.  Google each and decide which one you want to use.  I prefer the latter.

Comment: @DanBracuk I m using something like:

     <soapenv:Body>
        <newOrder soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
       <sor:newOrderRequest>
         <sor:SOrderRequest>
   <cfoutput>
            <sor:sID>S123</sor:sID>
....

Answer (score 2):

You have not shared complete code so some assumptions must be made.

Ben Nadel has a wonderful write up on this topic. You should definitely read this first: [Making SOAP Web Service Requests With ColdFusion And CFHTTP](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-Making-SOAP-Web-Service-Requests-With-ColdFusion-And-CFHTTP.htm)

Whenever I interact with SOAP services I usually end up using something similar to the following. It is very similar to the code fragment that you shared but you did not show (among other things) the content being wrapped in `<cfsavecontent>` tags to store the XML in the `soap` variable before making the `<cfhttp>` request. This could be your problem? The following is just an example to get you going.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soap">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:newOrder xmlns:ns1="urn:TripFlow" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sID>001</sID>
         <orderNumber>12345</orderNumber>
         <dateCreated>07/31/2013</dateCreated>
      </ns1:newOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- Invoke web service to send message--->
<cfhttp url="http://xxxx:123/YYY/SService" method="post" timeout="10">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml" />
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="""SService-method-name-here""" />
<!---<cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />  sometimes this is needed --->
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(soap)#" />
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
<cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Another invaluable tool when working with web services is [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). That should definitely be a part of your toolkit as well.  You can build your request using soapUI and check the responses.  Once you have it working with soapUI you can copy your request into your ColdFusion code.

Comment: Hi, I am using the exact code ..just like u have added..but getting 500 Internal Server Error .Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the 500 error in the response or from your ColdFusion server making the request?  Try making the SOAP request using SoapUI and see if that works.  Check your ColdFusion logs for more details about the error (if it is being generated on your server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Miguel-F .Finally used SOAPUI and understood what was going wrong.

Had set parameter throwonerror="Yes" .Because of this ParseException was going to error block rather than getting captured in code.

On setting throwonerror="No", the code finally started working and reading the response tags.

Comment: I have found SoapUI (and other similar tools) to be invaluable when working with web services. Glad you got it working.